# Type cast string to another type

Tags: string, flutter, dart, casting

I am not sure just how possible this is but I am trying to receive text 'BoxFit.cover' from my data source, then type cast it and have it assigned to a variable of type BoxFit. This will allow me to customise my application via my datasource which is on a cloud database

```
BoxFit kLoginScreenBoxFit = 'BoxFit.cover' as BoxFit;
```

I get an error " type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'BoxFit' in type cast". is there a way of doing this?

I am not sure just how possible this is but I am trying to receive text 'BoxFit.cover' from my data source, then type cast it and have it assigned to a variable of type BoxFit. This will allow me to customise my application via my datasource which is on a cloud database

```
BoxFit kLoginScreenBoxFit = 'BoxFit.cover' as BoxFit;
```

I get an error " type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'BoxFit' in type cast". is there a way of doing this?

Comment: How would I apply the same principle for classes. I have a class. I have a TextStle myTextStyle =  GoogleFonts.raleway(
  textStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BoxFit` is an `enum`. Therefore, you can match it by name by searching it's values like so:

```
BoxFit boxFit = BoxFit.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'BoxFit.cover');
```

Comment: Brilliant workaround without using reflection :D